# Custom Master Pages & Application pages & VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, module, master-pages

Platform Using: SharePoint Server 2010
Tools Using: Visual Studio 2010
Description/Question: I've developed a custom master page and I'm deploying my artifacts using Modules in Visual Studio 2010. Both the master page and images deployed to their correct location, but when I deploy my theme css file to the Themable folder under the styles folder, its not there. Here are my two questions/problems:

1. My css file does not deploy to the Styles Library/en-us/Themable/ library. In my module; the Module element my URL attribute value is **Style Library/en-us/Themable** and the RootWebOnly property is set to true.
2. Also I was wondering how can I deploy my custom master page to appear with all application pages? I know the Application.Master is the master page set for all applications, but how can I overried this? Powershell? Visual Studio?

Thank You in advance....

Comment: Here is module xml:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="ThemesModule" Url="Style Library/en-us/Themable" RootWebOnly="TRUE">
  <File Path="ThemesModule\IntranetTheme.css" Url="IntranetTheme.css" />
</Module>
</Elements>